Hilbert polynomial of the union of two intersecting lines
I am trying to compute the Hilbert polynomial of the union of two intersecting lines $L_1$ and $L_2$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$. In order to get it, I supposed WLOG that $L_1=Z(x,y)$ and $L_2=Z(y,z)$. Thus, the union $L_1 \cup L_2$ is equal to $Z((x,y) \cap (y,z))=Z(y,xz)$. So, the graded ring is:
$$
S(X)=k[x,y,z,t]/(y,xz) \cong k[x,z,t]/(xz),
$$
and we have the exact sequence:
$$
0 \rightarrow k[x,z,t] \rightarrow k[x,z,t] \rightarrow k[x,z,t]/(xz) \rightarrow 0,
$$
so that, for a big enough value (in this case, if $n \geq 2$), we have that:
$$
P_{L_1 \cup L_2}(n)=P_{\mathbb{P}^2}(n)-P_{\mathbb{P}^2}(n-2)=\binom{2+n}{2}-\binom{2+n-2}{2}=2n+1.
$$
So that the dimension is one (since it is the union of two lines) and the degree is two. I have two questions:

Is my solution right?

I have previously computed the Hilbert
polynomial of the union of two disjoint lines and gotten $2n+2$,
which makes sense, because every plane intersects two disjoint lines
in exactly two points. In the case of two intersecting lines,
almost every plane intersects the union of both lines at
two points. How does the Hilbert polynomial codify this?




Yes, this is fine.
The same way that it does for two disjoint lines: the leading coefficient of the Hilbert polynomial of $X$ is $\frac{\deg X}{(\dim X)!}$, and $\deg X$ has as one of its equivalent interpretations the number of intersection points of $X$ with a generic linear section of complimentary dimension. In both the case of skew lines and intersecting lines in $\Bbb P^3$, a generic 2-plane intersects the lines in two points.


Great, thanks!!
